# How to loop through all json items with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

This is the json file I am working with

```
?(
{
    "title":"1",
    "description":"description",
    "site":"site",
    "image_s":"/Becki.jpg",
    "image_l":"aurel"
},
{
    "title":"2",
    "description":"2",
    "site":"1",
    "image_s":"8.jpg",
    "image_l":"aurel"
})
```

The question mark is replaced with a dynamic number in order to over come cross-domain restrictions. And I think this is why I am having trouble

I am trying to get both image_s but I can only read the data of the first item (if that's the right word):

```
$.getJSON(surl,  function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(tete, i){
            $.each(data, function(tete, i){
                    $("<div>").addClass("box").append(
                        $("<img/>").attr("src", [this]))
                        ).appendTo("#showdata");
            });

        })
   });
```

I know there is something wrong with `$("<img/>").attr("src", [this]))` but that is not the problem. The problem is that the above loop only get the content of the first item (title:1 to the end not title:2)

I think if the name of the question mark wasn't dynamic I could have done the loop from there and got its children, but I dont know how to do that in this case

And in case you need to know, I can not use server-side programing for this particular project

Can you help in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your items (called objects in JavaScript) into array:

```
[
    {
        "title":"1",
        "description":"description",
        "site":"site",
        "image_s":"/Becki.jpg",
        "image_l":"aurel"
    },
    {
        "title":"2",
        "description":"2",
        "site":"1",
        "image_s":"8.jpg",
        "image_l":"aurel"
    }
]
```

And also change your JS:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item){
       $("<div>").addClass("box")
           .append($("<img/>").attr("src", [item.image_s]))
           .appendTo("#showdata");
});
```

Running example is shown in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msrKV/).

Comment: Thanks, It is not working for me though. This is the code that I have http://jsfiddle.net/msrKV/1/

Comment: Sure, I didn't add part fetching JSON from URL I hadn't known, so I just skipped line with `$.getJSON(surl,  function(data)` ;) In my fiddle I assigned objects array to `data` variable instead of fetching it from that function.

Comment: So is it possible to the code I have working or would I need to change to like you, Though I really wanted the json to be separate

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. Your fiddle should work if given `surl` returns valid json.

Comment: I am going to use your code as I can get mine working. I'm just going to divide the json content from the code so that I can manage them easier and that's it. Thanks

Comment: hey, do you know is there a way to do an if statement like: if(item.title == "something"){  though this is not working } Thanks

Comment: It should work anywhere inside `function(index, item)`. What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing data through another domain, you're probably using JSONP.  JSONP requires the server to return the values wrapped in a function; in your case, the function is a random string of numbers.

If your post is accurate, you'll have to update the server to return the JSON object properly:

Currently it is returning multiple objects wrapped by a function: `235235({one object}, {two object})`

When it should be returning one JSON object, wrapped by a function: `235235([{first object in array}, {second object in array}])`